# Java if statement with 2 conditions and common code

Tags: java, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I have 2 conditions to check, if one condition is true, I need to carry out some code and if another condition is true, I need to carry out some *different* code. However, if **either** is true, I need to carry out a common piece of code in addition to the specific code.

Note only one of the 2 conditions can be true, not both.

So, I could do this in 3 ways:

**Method 1**

```
if (condition1 || condition2){

    //common code here
    commonCode();
    moreCommonCode();

    //Dig a bit deeper to see which one was true
    if (condition1){

        //Carry out some code here specific to condition1
        specificToCondition1();
        moreCondition1Stuff();

    }

    else {

        //Carry out some code here specific to condition2
        specificToCondition2();
        moreCondition2Stuff();

    }

}
```

**Method 2**

```
if (condition1){

   specificToCondition1();
   moreCondition1Stuff();

}

else if (condition2){
    specificToCondition2();
    moreCondition2Stuff();

}

if (condition1 || condition2){

    commonCode();
    moreCommonCode();

}
```

**Method 3**

```
if (condition1){

    specificToCondition1();
    moreCondition1Stuff();
    commonCode();
    moreCommonCode();

}

else if (condition2){

    specificToCondition2();
    moreCondition2Stuff();
    commonCode();
    moreCommonCode();

 }
```

in **Method 1** and **Method 2**, I need to check the conditions twice.

In **Method 3** I have to duplicate the common code.

Am I missing something and is there a way to do this where I nether have to duplicate the code or check the conditions twice?

Comment: Checking a condition twice is not such an expensive operation. If anything expensive is involved, assign the result to a `boolean`.

Comment: @n0rd - oops. thanks, edited.  Note only one if the conditions can be true, not both.  Thanks.

Comment: Method1 is the most optimal. You can't save any more lines and it is not that taxing to do if checks on booleans, as @RealSkeptic mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 4** (using a private method for the common part)

So you don't have code duplications except of the call of the common method.

```
if (condition1) {
  specificToCondition1();
  moreCondition1Stuff();
  execCond1AndCond2Stuff();
}
else if (condition2) {
  specificToCondition2();
  moreCondition2Stuff();
  execCond1AndCond2Stuff();
}

void execCond1AndCond2Stuff() {
  commonCode();
  moreCommonCode();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tom, this seems to be the best option (if not using **Method1**, which seems to be the best of the 3 in the original question).

Comment: This is the same as method 3.

Comment: @CodeWhisperer It's not, even if it look similar imagine the common code part whould be much more complex, than your code duplications would increase dramaticlaly. And now considier it's not just a fun project and you have to test the copy-paste-code measuring statement, branch or what else coverage - you whould have to do it twice - it would be not maintainable anymore...

Comment: Yeah, this is something that I have contemplated doing and is an extension of method3, (simply putting the common code into another method), I was hoping to not even have to duplicate the method call, but this would cut down on writing the code twice (the code is quite a few lines long).  And I'm guessing either this or simply using option1 from the original Q are the best options.

Comment: @Zippy Yes, but duplicating the method call is for free (if you have performance in mind) since only one of both calls is performed, but of course, forgetting one of the calls would break the code.

Comment: @tom refactoring is good but even this has to be done in moderation otherwise there is really no benefit to it. In this scenario I think there is no benefit.

Comment: @CodeWhisperer OK, but I think it's because you just see these two duplicated lines of code - duplicating 2 lines is not that big deal and might be OK, but like Zippi mentioned _the code is quite a few lines long_ this is just a simplified example for a more complex scenario and then you shouldn't duplicate the code...

Answer (score 0):

```
bolean isSet = false;
if (condition1){ 
    specificToCondition1();       
    moreCondition1Stuff();
    isSet = true; 
} else if (condition2){  
    specificToCondition2();        
    moreCondition2Stuff(); 
    isSet = true;
}
if(isSet) {
     commonCode(); 
     moreCommonCode();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work with inheritance depending on what the real code are looking like. Here's an example of what I'm thinking. Bit more boilerplate code though...

```
package com.stackoverflow.condition;

public abstract class AbstractCase {

    public void doLogic() {
        // Some common logic
        doSpecificLogic();
    }

    abstract void doSpecificLogic();
}

package com.stackoverflow.condition;

public class CaseOne extends AbstractCase {
    @Override
    protected void doSpecificLogic() {
        // Specific logic
    }
}

package com.stackoverflow.condition;

public class CaseTwo extends AbstractCase {
    @Override
    protected void doSpecificLogic() {
        // Specific logic
    }
}

package com.stackoverflow.condition;

public class CaseFactory {

    public static AbstractCase getCase(boolean caseOne) {
        return caseOne ? new CaseOne() : new CaseTwo();
    }
}

package com.stackoverflow.condition;

public class Implementation {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        CaseFactory.getCase(true).doLogic();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think it's a bit over-engineered?

Comment: Meets criteria of no double check nor code duplication at least :D

Comment: I think this code is trying to add a rocket engine to a pen while still trying to maintain the functionality of the pen.